# templates not visible in sp 2007

Tags: 2007

i have installed sharepoint on new machine .
i am unable to find any templates while i am creating sites . 
can anyone explain how to get the templates ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SharePoint 2010 there's a link on the **Site Settings** page called *Page layouts and site templates* accessible directly by navigating to /_Layouts/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx.

In SharePoint 2007 I can't remember if the link text is the same, but you should be able to navigate to it directly using the same url.

From there you can pick & choose which templates will be available for use in your site.